# selenium Instagram scraper duplication

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, instagram, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrap Instagram by hash tag in this case **dog** using selenium

1. scroll to load images
2. get links of posts for loaded images

but I realized that most of the links are repeated (last 3 lines) I don't know what is the problem I even tried many libraries for Instagram scrapping but all of them either giving errors or don't search by hash tag. 
I am trying to scrap Instagram to get image data for my  Deep Learning classifier model
also I want to know if there are better methods for Instagram scraping

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC

driver = webdriver.Edge("msedgedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")

tag = "dog"
numberOfScrolls = 70

### Login Section ###

time.sleep(3)
username_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[1]/div/label/input')
username_field.send_keys("myusername")

password_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[2]/div/label/input')
password_field.send_keys("mypassword")
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]').click()
time.sleep(5)

### Scarping Section ###

link = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + tag
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(5)
Links = []
for i in range(numberOfScrolls):
    AC(driver).send_keys(Keys.END).perform()  # scrolls to the bottom of the page
    time.sleep(1)
    for x in range(1, 8):
        try:
            row = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[' + str(i) + ']')
            row = row.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
            for element in row:
                if element.get_attribute("href") is not None:
                    print(element.get_attribute("href"))
                    Links.append(element.get_attribute("href"))
        except:
            continue

print(len(Links))
Links = list(set(Links))
print(len(Links))
```

Comment: If you scroll and get elements and then scroll you will always get duplicates. If you scroll stop and then get elements you will get all the values until the scroll.

Comment: Just move the obtaining elements outside the scroll simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it found what was my mistake

`row=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="reactroot"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div/div[' + str(i) + ']')`
specifically in this part `str(i)` it should be **x** instead of **i** thats why most of them where repeated